# USB stick with read-only file system

Tags: usb, filesystem, read-only

I have a USB stick, and I just want to format it. But when I try to do it with *Nautilus* or *Gparted*, there is an error because the USB stick file system is read-only...

I found some posts about it, and I try commands like :

```
 mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdx
 hdparm -r0 /dev/sdx
 dosfsck -a /dev/sdx1
 mkfs.msdos -F 32 /dev/sdx1
 mkfs.msdos -F 32 /dev/sdx1
```

Replacing the *x* of `/dev/sdx` by the right letter of course.

But each time, I have a message telling me that *the operation is not allowed because of read-only*.

How can I format my USB stick and remove this read-only mode please ?

Comment: Are you sure the USB stick does not have a (hardware) switch that makes it read-only? Open `gnome-disks` and try to delete any partitions on the USB stick drive.

Comment: That depends on the USB stick. Missing info: where is it from? If store bought does it have a switch on the side? If you got it from a convention or seminair: most of those USB sticks are -internally- set to read only and you can not use them for anything else. Also: if it has a windows filesystem that got corrupted linux will refuse to mount it writeable.

Comment: Yes, I do not see any switch on the USB stick. With `gnome-disks`,all options like `Format...`, `Edit partition...`, `Edit Filesystem...`, etc... are disabled. The USB stick is coming from a Store, and I know that it was only used on a Windows computer... But the problem is the same on Windows : I can't remove the read-only mode.

Comment: It's probably defective. Becoming read-only is the first indication it's about to fail.

Comment: Have you tried wiping the USB device completely with dd i.e.
```dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx```
Then attempt formatting with Gparted etc
Worth a try before putting it in the bin

Comment: I just tried `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx`, but I have an error : > dd: impossible to open '/dev/sdx' : read-only filesystem... There is no solution to reset the USB stick ?

Comment: No, there isn't. Put it in the recycling bin for inorganics.

Comment: There are more details and tips in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

Comment: If due to using as an installer with ISO9660 partition, unmount using Disks, then create new partition table using GParted. If other reason sudodus' comment worth a shot. Unfortunately GabrielaGarcia is probably correct.

Comment: In the same way, I can't create a new partition table with GParted..